# Webpage is not being rendered properly

Tags: html, angular, rendering

Hi I am an android developer and haven't much knowledge about web, I purchased this [App](https://codecanyon.net/item/vido-android-youtube-multi-channel-10/22690985?s_rank=1) and it has a [web back-end](https://lrfreepresets.com/androidapp/backend.zip), it working pretty fine when I run it local like this,

[image: When run locally]

but when I run this via hosting , I am getting this. [link](https://lrfreepresets.com/androidapp/index.html)

[image: After uploading on hosting]

After going through some search I found that these are some sort of Angular tags, as I already have mentioned that I haven't knowledge about this, How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> It's happening due to hosting or path resolution issues.

None of the JavaScript files are getting loaded due to which the page is breaking and hence you are seeing raw code.

Fixing the proper loading of JS should fix the page. You might need to tweak it further in case relative path's are not loaded correctly.
Overall, it is not a code level issue yet.

Below is the screenshot of the hosted link you shared.

[image: https://lrfreepresets.com/androidapp/index.html]

Comment: Bro why is it running properly in local?? I have attached web back-end zip file.. Thats running fine locally.